# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 368, 1, 1, 1], expected input[2, 64, 8, 90, 60] to have 368 channels, but got 64 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to run my network, but the number of channels is not correct. I've been thinking about it for a few days and fixing it, but it hasn't been fixed and I don't know at all.

The number of the first input channels of the ChannelAttention class is set to in_planes. In the InceptionModule_with_CBAM class, the out_channels of branch1 are [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32], so the number of first input channels of the ChannelAttention class, in_planes, is 64+ 96+ 128 + 16 + 32 + 32 = 368.
of the I3D_with_CBAM class
Looking at self.inception2 =InceptionModule_with_CBAM(256, [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64]), the number of input channels is 256, which is different from 368, so Given groups=1, weight of size [23, 368, 1, 1, 1], expected input[1, 256, 1, 1, 1] to have 368 channels, but got 256 channels instead error occurs.

num_classes and args["num_class"] are 1, batch_size is 1, args["img_size"] is (360, 240). So image for training is (360, 240)

The reason why the shape is not written next to the commented print statement or print statement is because it is not output.

And here is my network.

```
class CBAM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super(CBAM, self).__init__()
        self.channel_attention = ChannelAttention(in_channels)
        print('CBAM in_channels1', in_channels)  # 368, 640, 624, 648, 664, 704, 1024, 1264
        self.spatial_attention = SpatialAttention(channel=in_channels)
        print('CBAM in_channels2', in_channels)  # 368, 640, 624, 648, 664, 704, 1024, 1264


    def forward(self, x):
        x_out = self.channel_attention(x)
        print('cbam channel_attention: ', x_out.shape)  # 368, 640, 624, 648, 664, 704, 1024, 1264
        x_out = self.spatial_attention(x_out)
        print('cbam spatial_attention: ', x_out.shape)  # 368, 640, 624, 648, 664, 704, 1024, 1264
        return x_out

class ChannelAttention(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_planes, ratio=16):
        super(ChannelAttention, self).__init__()
        self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d(1)
        self.max_pool = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool3d(1)

        self.fc1 = nn.Conv3d(in_planes, in_planes // ratio, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        print('channel attnetion1', in_planes)  # 368, 640, 624, 648, 664, 704, 1024, 1264
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.fc2 = nn.Conv3d(in_planes // ratio, in_planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        print('channel attnetion2', in_planes)  # 368, 640, 624, 648, 664, 704, 1024, 1264
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        print('0', x.shape) # 0 torch.Size([1, 256, 500, 60, 90])
        avg_pool = self.avg_pool(x)
        print('1', avg_pool.shape) # 1 torch.Size([1, 256, 1, 1, 1])
        max_pool = self.max_pool(x)
        print('2', max_pool.shape) # 2 torch.Size([1, 256, 1, 1, 1])
        avg_pool = self.fc1(avg_pool)
        print('3', avg_pool.shape)
        max_pool = self.fc1(max_pool)
        print('4', max_pool.shape)
        avg_pool = self.relu(avg_pool)
        print('5', avg_pool.shape)
        max_pool = self.relu(max_pool)
        print('6', max_pool.shape)
        avg_pool = self.fc2(avg_pool)
        print('7', avg_pool.shape)
        max_pool = self.fc2(max_pool)
        print('8', max_pool.shape)
        x_out = self.sigmoid(avg_pool + max_pool)
        print('9', x_out.shape)
        return x_out

class SpatialAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channel, reduction_ratio=8):
        super(SpatialAttention, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv3d_BN(channel, channel // reduction_ratio, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.conv2 = Conv3d_BN(channel // reduction_ratio, channel, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x_out = x.mean(dim=2, keepdim=True).mean(dim=3, keepdim=True).mean(dim=4, keepdim=True)
        print('spatial_attention_xout1: ', x_out.shape)
        # x_out = x.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True)
        x_out = self.conv1(x_out)
        print('spatial_attention_xout2: ', x_out.shape)
        x_out = self.conv2(x_out)
        print('spatial_attention_xout3: ', x_out.shape)
        x_out = self.sigmoid(x_out)
        print('spatial_attention_xout4: ', x_out.shape)
        return x * x_out

class Conv3d_BN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, groups=1, bias=False):
        super(Conv3d_BN, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, groups=groups, bias=bias)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        return x

class InceptionModule_with_CBAM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(InceptionModule_with_CBAM, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        
        self.branch1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(sum(out_channels), out_channels[0], kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[0]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
        print('out_channels1', out_channels)  # [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32], [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64], [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64], [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64], [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64], [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64], [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128], [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128]

        self.branch2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(sum(out_channels), out_channels[1], kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[1]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv3d(out_channels[1], out_channels[2], kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[2]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
        print('out_channels2',out_channels)  # [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32], [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64], [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64], [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64], [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64], [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64], [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128], [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128]

        self.branch3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(sum(out_channels), out_channels[3], kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[3]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv3d(out_channels[3], out_channels[4], kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[4]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
        print('out_channels3',out_channels)  # [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32], [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64], [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64], [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64], [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64], [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64], [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128], [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128]

        self.branch4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.Conv3d(sum(out_channels), out_channels[5], kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[5]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
        print('out_channels4', out_channels)  # [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32], [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64], [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64], [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64], [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64], [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64], [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128], [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128]

        out_channels_sum = sum(out_channels)
        print('out_channels_sum', out_channels_sum)
        self.cbam = CBAM(out_channels_sum) 

    def forward(self, x):
        # print('in_channels:', self.in_channels)
        print('in_channels:', x.shape)  # torch.Size([1, 64, 500, 60, 90])
        x1 = self.branch1(x)
        print('x1', x1.shape) # x1 torch.Size([1, 64, 500, 60, 90])
        x2 = self.branch2(x)
        print('x2', x2.shape) # x2 torch.Size([1, 128, 500, 60, 90])
        x3 = self.branch3(x)
        print('x3', x3.shape) # x3 torch.Size([1, 32, 500, 60, 90])
        x4 = self.branch4(x)
        print('x4', x4.shape)

        if x1.shape[1] != x4.shape[1]:
            x4 = self.conv1x1(x4)

        x = torch.cat((x1, x2, x3, x4), 1)
        # x = torch.cat([branch1, branch2, branch3, branch4, branch5, branch6], dim=1)
        print(x.shape) # torch.Size([1, 256, 500, 60, 90])
        x = self.cbam(x)
        return x


class I3D_with_CBAM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=args["num_class"]):
        super(I3D_with_CBAM, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), stride=(2, 2, 2), padding=(3, 3, 3)),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2))
        )

        self.inception1 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(64, [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception1.in_channels
        # self.cbam1 = CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels))

        self.inception2 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels), [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception2.in_channels
        # self.cbam2 = CBAM(sum(self.inception2.out_channels))

        self.inception3a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception2.out_channels), [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception3a.in_channels
        # self.cbam3 = CBAM(sum(self.inception3a.out_channels))

        self.inception3b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception3a.out_channels), [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception3b.in_channels
        # self.cbam4 = CBAM(sum(self.inception3b.out_channels))

        self.inception4a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception3b.out_channels), [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception4a.in_channels
        # self.cbam5 = CBAM(sum(self.inception4a.out_channels))

        self.inception4b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception4a.out_channels), [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception4b.in_channels
        # self.cbam6 = CBAM(sum(self.inception4b.out_channels))

        self.inception5a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception4b.out_channels), [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception5a.in_channels
        # self.cbam7 = CBAM(sum(self.inception5a.out_channels))

        self.inception5b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception5a.out_channels), [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128])
        # self.in_channels = self.inception5b.in_channels
        # self.cbam8 = CBAM(sum(self.inception5b.out_channels))

        self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d(1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(256, 64)
        self.linear4 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=num_classes), nn.Sigmoid())

    def forward(self, x):
        # x = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3, 4)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM conv1: ', x.shape) # torch.Size([1, 64, 500, 60, 90])
        x = self.inception1(x) # 여기서 RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [23, 368, 1, 1, 1], expected input[1, 256, 1, 1, 1] to have 368 channels, but got 256 channels instead
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception1: ', x.shape) # torch.Size([2, 368, 5, 5, 5])
        # x = self.cbam1(self.inception1.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception2(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception2: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam2(self.inception2.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception3a(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception3a: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam3(self.inception3a.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception3b(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception3b: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam4(self.inception3b.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception4a(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception4a: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam5(self.inception4a.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception4b(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception4b: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam6(self.inception4b.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception5a(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception5a: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam7(self.inception5a.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.inception5b(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM inception5b: ', x.shape) #
        # x = self.cbam8(self.inception5.out_channels[-1])

        x = self.avg_pool(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM avg_pool: ', x.shape) #
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM view: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.dropout(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM dropout: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.linear1(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM linear1: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.dropout(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM dropout: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.linear2(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM linear2: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.dropout(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM dropout: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.linear3(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM linear3: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.dropout(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM dropout: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.linear4(x)
        print('I3D_with_CBAM linear4: ', x.shape) #
        x = self.dropout(x)

        return x
```

**Output**

> Given groups=1, weight of size [23, 368, 1, 1, 1], expected input[1, 256, 1, 1, 1] to have 368 channels, but got 256 channels instead error occurs.

**Expected**

> Training..

I tried to change I3D_with_CBAM:

```
class I3D_with_CBAM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=args["num_class"]):
        super(I3D_with_CBAM, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), stride=(2, 2, 2), padding=(3, 3, 3)),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2))
        )

        self.inception1 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(64, [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32])
        self.inception2 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels), [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64])
        self.inception3a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception2.out_channels), [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64])
        self.inception3b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception3a.out_channels), [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64])
        self.inception4a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception3b.out_channels), [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64])
        self.inception4b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception4a.out_channels), [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64])
        self.inception5a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception4b.out_channels), [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128])
        self.inception5b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception5a.out_channels), [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128])

        self.cbam1 = CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels))
        self.cbam2 = CBAM(sum(self.inception2.out_channels))
        self.cbam3a = CBAM(sum(self.inception3a.out_channels))
        self.cbam3b = CBAM(sum(self.inception3b.out_channels))
        self.cbam4a = CBAM(sum(self.inception4a.out_channels))
        self.cbam4b = CBAM(sum(self.inception4b.out_channels))
        self.cbam5a = CBAM(sum(self.inception5a.out_channels))
        self.cbam5b = CBAM(sum(self.inception5b.out_channels))

        self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d(1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, num_classes)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.inception1(x)
        x = self.cbam1(x)
        x = self.inception2(x)
        x = self.cbam2(x)
        x = self.inception3a(x)
        x = self.cbam3a(x)
        x = self.inception3b(x)
        x = self.cbam3b(x)
        x = self.inception4a(x)
        x = self.cbam4a(x)
        x = self.inception4b(x)
        x = self.cbam4b(x)
        x = self.inception5a(x)
        x = self.cbam5a(x)
        x = self.inception5b(x)
        x = self.cbam5b(x)
        x = self.avg_pool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

and

````
class InceptionModule_with_CBAM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(InceptionModule_with_CBAM, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels

        self.branch1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels[0], kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels[0]),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
``` in this code, nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels[0], kernel_size=1) I changed in_channels to sum(out_channels).

And,
````

class I3D_with_CBAM(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, num_classes=args["num_class"]):
super(I3D_with_CBAM, self).**init**()

```
    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), stride=(2, 2, 2), padding=(3, 3, 3)),
        nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2))
    )

    self.inception1 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(64, [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception1.in_channels
    # self.cbam1 = CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels))

    self.inception2 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels), [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception2.in_channels
    # self.cbam2 = CBAM(sum(self.inception2.out_channels))

    self.inception3a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception2.out_channels), [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception3a.in_channels
    # self.cbam3 = CBAM(sum(self.inception3a.out_channels))

    self.inception3b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception3a.out_channels), [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception3b.in_channels
    # self.cbam4 = CBAM(sum(self.inception3b.out_channels))

    self.inception4a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception3b.out_channels), [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception4a.in_channels
    # self.cbam5 = CBAM(sum(self.inception4a.out_channels))

    self.inception4b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception4a.out_channels), [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception4b.in_channels
    # self.cbam6 = CBAM(sum(self.inception4b.out_channels))

    self.inception5a = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception4b.out_channels), [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception5a.in_channels
    # self.cbam7 = CBAM(sum(self.inception5a.out_channels))

    self.inception5b = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception5a.out_channels), [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128])
    # self.in_channels = self.inception5b.in_channels
    # self.cbam8 = CBAM(sum(self.inception5b.out_channels))

    self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d(1)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(256, 64)
    self.linear4 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=num_classes), nn.Sigmoid())
```

```
self.inception1 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(64, [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32])
Fixed input channel values such as 64 have been modified to values such as 368 (the number of input channels when an error occurred for the first time).

And I tried it with this value too.
```

self.inception2 = InceptionModule_with_CBAM(sum(self.inception1.out_channels), [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64])

```
But I got same error.
I got error like this yet. But at that time, I could change using permute. But this time, it's not that case. I was so frustrated. Thank you for your help.
Commented networks are unused. I don't know what should I do. Thank you for reading and your help.
If you know me what should I do, I really appreciate it.
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).